# .NET Framework 4.6 and ADO.NET

Tags: asp.net

Using .NET Framework 4.5 in VS2015 one has the ability  to add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model but the option does not seem to exists with .NET Framework 4.6. I've reviewed the release notes but there does not seem to be any mention of a new approach so any  hint would be helpful.

Comment: The Entity Framework is now distinct and separate from the .NET Framework.

Comment: Yes indeed, Microsoft changed their approach, now using NuGet to bring in components previously baked in but my question remains: how does one add an ADO.NET Entity Data Model or where has Microsoft documented the new approach.